# Buscador php para archivos txt

Tags: php, array, archivo, buscador

quiero ver si es posible que la comunidad me ayude en este buscador que estoy creando.

Me explico de que se trata, es un conjunto de archivos txt que se obtienen de exportar los chats de la aplicación whastapp. El formato de estos chat se caracterizan porque inician con la fecha hora nombre de quien realiza el comentario o # de teléfono, algo más o menos así:

> 05/09/18 6:54 a.m. - Elena Hidalgo Corredora: SKY GROUP VENDE BAJON DE PRECIO REF100000REF Y REF40000REF
>   ☆☆☆☆Terreno en Colinas de Guataparo de 1500M2 con cerca perimetral, puntos electricos, tanque de agua, porton electrico, baños, construccion avanzada, via principal y listo para firmar. 300.000. AHORA 100.000
>   Otro de 830M2 con cerca perimetral en 60.000Ref. AHORA 40.000

Tengo el problema parcialmente resuelto, por un lado tengo un formulario de búsqueda donde la persona coloca algo así:

> Apartamento Tulipán San Diego 10.000

Una búsqueda cualquiera, eso es sólo un ejemplo. Qué hecho:

1. A través de una archivo php, recojo a través del método post la información del formulario.
2. Convierto dicha información en un array con la finalidad de buscar cada palabra en el archivo txt.
3. He convertido el archivo txt en un array para iterar en cada fecha, buscar en mi opinión más fácilmente y presentar la información ordenada.

Los resultados son aceptables, pero no es exactamente lo que busco, porque resulta que me itera palabra por palabra y muestra como resultado todas las claves que contenta la palabra Apartamento y si existe una que contenga Apartamento y Tulipán, la muestra 2 veces, así lo hace con cada palabra.

Lo que quiero es que me muestre solamente las claves que contengan las 3 ó 4 palabras que está indicando el formulario. Aquí les dejó el código php:

```
//Capturamos la búsqueda
$busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

$arrayb = explode (" ", $busqueda);  

$array = explode("|", file_get_contents('chat'.$fecha.'.txt'));

for($i=0 ;$i<count($array);$i++)
{

    for($u=0 ;$u<count($arrayb);$u++)
    {
         $found=stripos($array[$i],$arrayb[$u]);
         if($found)
         {?>
            <div class='contaniner'>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <?php echo $array[$i];
                        echo "<br><br>";?>      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php 
         }         
    }
}
```

Aquí les dejo la demo, solamente pueden usarse la 5 primeras fechas del mes de septiembre 2018. [buscador php en archivos planos](http://pruebawebapp.byethost4.com/buscador/)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En el planteamiento de la pregunta no ha quedado claro cuál es el tipo de búsqueda que quieres. ¿Si se escribe esto: `Apartamento Tulipán San Diego 10.000` qué tipo de coincidencias se requieren: todo ese texto únicamente, parte de ese texto (qué parte en ese caso)...? Debes explicarte mejor y mostrar un pequeño ejemplo de cómo están organizados tus datos.

Comment: Debería mostrar todas las claves del array que contengan estas tres palabras inclusive, pero no mostrarme las que contengan solamente Apartamento por ejemplo. Y los datos está organizados como un array, es decir, el archivo plano, está representado algo así: Array (1) => [0] 05/09/18 6:54 a.m. - Elena Hidalgo Corredora: SKY GROUP VENDE BAJON DE PRECIO REF100000REF Y REF40000REF ☆☆☆☆Terreno en Colinas... [1] 05/09/18 6:54 a.m. - Elena Hidalgo Corredora: SKY GROUP VENDE BAJON DE PRECIO REF100000REF Y REF40000REF ☆☆☆☆Terreno en Colinas... cada fecha es una clave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejando aparte que sería mejor usar algún tipo de base de datos que permita búsqueda de texto completo (full-text search), te pongo cómo creo que debería quedar la parte de filtrado de los elementos para que aparezcan solo aquellos que contengan todas las palabras que hayas buscado

Para obtener los elementos que contengan todas las palabras, usamos una variable que controle la cantidad de veces que coincide:

```
$arrayb = explode (" ", $busqueda);  
$array = explode("|", file_get_contents('chat'.$fecha.'.txt'));
$results = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $line = $array[$i];
    // Reiniciamos el contador de coincidencias de palabras para esta línea (o entrada en el chat)
    $numberOfFounds = 0;
    for ($u = 0; $u < count($arrayb); $u++)
    {
        $found = stripos($line, $arrayb[$u]);
        if ($found)
        {
            // Si coincide, sumamos uno en el contador de coincidencias
            $numberOfFounds++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Si alguna palabra no coincide, dejamos de comprobar el resto para esa línea
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($numberOfFounds == count($arrayb))
    {
        // Si la línea (o entrada de chat) contiene todas las palabras, la añadimos al array de resultados
        array_push($results, $line);
    }
}

// Recorremos el array de resultados para mostrarlos al usuario
foreach ($results as $result) {
<div class='contaniner'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <?= $result ?><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
} ?>
```

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero evitar, ya que a diario se generan hasta 180 publicaciones en grupo, son como 20 grupos de whatsapp y quiero es crear un buscador basado en archivo de texto plano. Sin embargo, voy a probar tu código y estoy avisando si es lo que estoy buscando, muchas gracias.

Comment: Solamente hay una corrección al código y es lo siguiente hay que coloca un echo en $result, pero funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias Javi.